# How to insert blank values(instead of NULL) into SQL Server from SAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I'm looking for instruction on how to insert blank values into SQL Server when loading data from SAS. Currently the SAS values are the equivalent of '', but when loaded to SQL Server they show up as NULL.

Tried making the insert value '', still shows up as NULL.

Comment: If you want "blank" then you need to insert `''`.  However, that only works for string columns.  And `NULL` is more reasonable.

Comment: Show the code you are using to insert values.  Can you modify the SQL Server table definitions ?

Comment: Why do you want blank values in your character variable? Also is the variable defined as CHAR or VARCHAR in the database?  Do you want to set the value to one blank? two blanks? Or do you want to set it to an empty string. Not sure why you would ever want (or allow) VARCHAR values to have empty but non-null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that SAS uses fixed length character variables. So trailing spaces are meaningless as they are just there to fill the fixed length.  SAS will treat any value that is all blanks as missing.  You can control how it tries to insert these all blank values into the remote database using the [NULLCHAR=](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=n1hmopc3y74oy2n1svhu03pfoiy9.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) dataset option.

> Syntax NULLCHAR=SAS | YES | NO
>
> SAS indicates that
>   missing character values in SAS data sets are treated as NULL values
>   if the DBMS allows these. Otherwise, they are treated as the
>   NULLCHARVAL= value.
>
> YES indicates that missing character values in SAS data sets are
>   treated as NULL values if the DBMS allows these. Otherwise, an error
>   is returned.
>
> NO indicates that missing character values in SAS data sets are
>   treated as the NULLCHARVAL= value—regardless of whether the DBMS
>   allows NULL values for the column.